# e2label error message

Tags: mount, encryption

I am trying to rename 3 HDD, previously encrypted with Utility Disk. The problem is that whenever I try to use the e2label from CLI i get the following error msg: Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

After issuing the command `sudo blkid` I get this output (for the specific drive I want to change the name):

```
/dev/sdg: UUID="91f2b009-a0fc-4878-9c69-98ded9a8dfcf" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"

/dev/mapper/udisks-luks-uuid-91f2b009-a0fc-4878-9c69-98ded9a8dfcf-uid1000: LABEL="RED" UUID="bdfb90cd-856f-4565-ab91-1704ce7b8595" TYPE="ext4"
```

Is `e2label` the right command to use?

Mainly, what i want to do is to change the name of the HDD that appears in the left panel of Nautilus before decrypting it.

I've followed the thread on this page but i've gone nowhere:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=94153

Comment: You need to first decrypt the partitions and then use the partition listed in /dev/mapper . If the command is not working, post the output of `ls /dev/mapper` and the exact command you used. As in your first question, you keep using /dev/sdg, which refers to the entier disk, and not a partition. you need to use /dev/mapper/partition if in addition you are using LUKS.

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` will also tell you which partitions are available on which drives, you probably want to run `e2label` on the right partition, like /dev/sdg1 or whichever it is. I don't know the exact `e2label` command you're trying so I'm not sure.

But just noticed it looks like your hard drive partition is encrypted with LUKS? That could change things, you may need to run `e2label` on the mapped / unencrypted partition, maybe  `/dev/mapper/udisks-luks-uuid-91f2b009-a0fc-4878-9c69-98ded9a8dfcf-uid1000` if that's it? And is "RED" the name you want to change? Editing `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/crypttab` to change the `LABEL=` there might be required after you change the fs label so that fstab or crypttab knows which disk to mount if it's mounting by label.